# Nodejs, EJS helper functions not work for include function.!

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I use nodeJS and express v3*,

i want to execute `include("someFile.ejs")` in some helper function, so that i can be called from any EJS template?

my code in app.js, server side:

```
app.locals.getFile= function(){ 

  include("someFile.ejs")
  include("someOneFile.ejs")
  include("someTwoFile.ejs")

  return 'all is well';

}
```

my code in Ejs:

```
<% getFile() %>
```

so the problem is: i expected `include("someFile.ejs")` run on ejs file but it didn't! what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
app.locals.getFile= function(){ 

<%include someOneFile%>
<%include someOneFile%>
<%include someOneFile%>
return 'all is well';

}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to improve it.  Don't use comments for that purpose.

Comment: thanks @ashish-mulani, but when i test it, i face to syntax error

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
app.locals.getFile = function()
{
    return `
        <%- include("someFile.ejs") %>
        <%- include("someOneFile.ejs") %>
        <%- include("someTwoFile.ejs") %>
        all is well
    `
}
```